# Why doesn't my bash script allow me to enter the python shell?

Tags: bash

I wrote a super simple bash script to get me into a python shell with everything set up like I need but it never actually enters the python shell. What am I doing wrong?

```
sudo su runnerdude
. /home/runnerdude/foo/env/bin/activate
cd /home/runnerdude/foo/bar
python manage.py shell
```

Comment: Try `sh -x script` and show the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is in the way sudo works. Assume your script is called run_python.sh:

```
. /home/runnerdude/foo/env/bin/activate
cd /home/runnerdude/foo/bar
python manage.py shell
```

Then you can invoke it with:

```
sudo -u runnerdude run_python.sh
```

Or, if you insist, your script might looks like:

```
sudo -u runnerdude '. /home/runnerdude/foo/env/bin/activate; \
    cd /home/runnerdude/foo/bar; \
    python manage.py shell'
```

Note the single quotes and the backslashes to join the commands together. To run your script:

```
run_python.sh
```

Comment: pedantically, don't need the line continuation chars inside single quotes.